# Can´t open my c# app on some Windows 7 computers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I´m receiving the following logs from the system events. I have no idea why this only happens on some machines:

> Level: Information; Source: Windows Error Reporting
>
> Detail: 756021398 30 CLR20r3 Not available 0 DayZ Ambient Launcher.exe 1.0.0.0 59d3d3b2 System.Windows.Forms 4.7.2558.0 59d4145b 63d 36 PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
>   C:\Users\kevo1414\AppData\Local\Temp\WERAA52.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_DayZ Ambient Lau_4e74decfa163bcb1cc9a3fc7dd961b8b6b975b8_108bafbf
>   0 093ea276-bf39-11e7-b709-902b345e4b59 0
>
> Level: Error Source: Application Error
>
> Detail:
>   DayZ Ambient Launcher.exe 1.0.0.0 59d3d3b2 KERNELBASE.dll 6.1.7601.23915 59b94abb e0434352 0000c54f 1498 01d35345cae21649 C:\Users\kevo1414\Downloads\DayZ Ambient Launcher 1.1 [eXWoLL,Cobblest0ne]\DayZ Ambient Launcher.exe C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll 093ea276-bf39-11e7-b709-902b345e4b59
>
> Level: Error Source: .NET Runtime
>
> Detail:
>   Application: DayZ Ambient Launcher.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 >Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(System.Guid ByRef, System.Object, Int32, System.Guid ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(System.String, System.Guid) at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(System.Guid) at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance() at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate() at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32) at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle() at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean) at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit() at dayz64.Form1.InitializeComponent() at dayz64.Form1..ctor() at dayz64.Program.Main()

Comment: What are you hosting in `AxHost`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Probably one of the sound dlls (WM player or VLC), they´re the only ones using activex. I have them both, since the program is meant to play 2 sounds/tracks at the same time.

Comment: AS per error stack trace, it seems that the COM component dll is not properly registered on system. you have to re-register the dll on that system and then use ur application. For your reference "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2181bee-bf6f-4c7a-963a-c48a12f677fa/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdbeclassnotreg?forum=winformsdesigner"

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible causes that I can see: operating system mismatch, or .NET installation mismatch.

Windows 7 was around right when x64 was being introduced, so there are some installations that either use x32 or x64, and going between them can result in issues if you don't install the right version of the application.

If you're going to run this application on a Windows 7 computer, then open the Start Menu, right click on Computer, and click on properties. You can see the specs of the operating system you're running from there.

The second possible issue is a .NET installation issue - maybe you have an outdated version of .NET installed, or the application relies on a legacy version of .NET and can't run on the newer frameworks, in which case you would need to look up the specifications of the product and the version you're using.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I tried creating a separate x86 and x64 versions of the program, but both of them give the same errors when launching (app just doesn´t launch).

The users updated their .NET 4.5.2 and 4.6 (which are the ones used here), with no result :/. I´m just trying to figure out if the problem is in the coding or in those individual w7 instances.

Comment: A 32/64-bit mismatch causes a module load failure, not an error from trying to instantiate a COM object.